# Why does typescript throw an error when assigning an object directly but not when assigning it through a third variable?

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```
interface User {
  id: number; 
  name: string;
}

const newUser = {id: 5, name: "Tom", age: 22}

// throws no error
const user1: User = newUser

// throws:
// Type '{ id: number; name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'User'.
const user2: User = {id: 5, name: "Tom", age: 22}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANzL7lxURnphSgDm9uAX1y4EAexCdyEAO4YsAXhzEyAVgA0LNmQBEAFVFVtGuD3bIATOaEjxkipigBGMnKjJFIGa5sSwye9DmLg7uSqTI6ppmegZGyCZmlkJAA)

Why is the first assignment ok and the second one not, even though they do pretty much the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find it in the latest docs, but you've run into ["excess property checks"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). They're... quirky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from the excess-property check on literal objects ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)). The documentation is a little sparse on the reasoning behind it though, which is not actually that complex.

In the first example, `newUser` may appear in other parts of the code besides the assignment to `user1`, so even though we won't access `age` on `user1`, it may still be accessed elsewhere.

For the second example this is not the case. The `age` property cannot be accessed on `user2`, which means there is no typed way to access this property, and it is most likely an error.